# inno setup install script and windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, inno-setup

any recommendations about those inno setup scripts so the compiled install run smoothly on windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't install anything to user-directories. Assume the installer will be run from a different account than the one that will use the installed application.
- If you need to save user-specific stuff install it as a template to a shared location (ideally read-only to regular users, e.g. under `{app}`) and have your application copy it from there on first startup.
- Don't create Quick Launch shortcuts

Comment: I use DestDir: like  {sys}\; and  {app}\
I got problem with my "INI" file witch the user could modify.
Witch {} location should I use for this if I want to share it to all users?

Comment: I also go a ".mdb", witch need to create a "LDB" and goes in a {app}\subFoler\ by default (the location is modifiable). where should I put it i I need To share it.

Comment: @DavRob60: Where you put user-modifiable files depends on whether the modifications should be per-user or per-machine. If they're per-user I'd put them under `{userappdata}`, otherwise under `{commonappdata}`. The important thing is that copying to `{userappdata}` should not be done by the installer but by the app itself.

Answer (score 1):

Oliver Giesen's suggestion is what I'm using, but it has a disadvantage... there seems to be no way to remove the {userappdata} folders for all users when uninstalling the program, meaning you can never do a clean uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: In the end, what I did for this was let the program itself keep a list of the {userappdata} settings folders of all users that started the program, in a textfile in {commonappdata}. Then I wrote an uninstall routine into the program to uninstall the user info of all of these folders, and made the inno uninstaller call that by launching the program with parameter '-uninstall'. This worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup has full support for Windows 7. Just make sure to use the latest version of Inno Seup, preferably the Unicode edition.