# Write to AppData directory using InnoIDE?

Tags: inno-setup, appdata, userappdatapath

I need to write to the:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\AppName

folder during the setup process. I'm using the InnoIDE program for setup, and it's awesome. However, it seems to be lacking an 'AppData' special folder for easily accessing that directory.

For example, you can use:
`DestDir: "{app}"`
to write the application directory.

But how do you get to AppData? Is there a list of all the preset DestDir options?

Comment: An elevated setup can not reliably write to the user's profile. This should be left to the application or write data to `{commonappdata}` for the application to read from.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arg, got it.

`{userappdata}` → C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\AppName

as found here:
http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup/msg74694.html

Comment: This do not work.. i have to write the the same folder... and do not work. Am using Windows 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

As you said in your own answer, **{userappdata}** is the one you need. The [help manual](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) has a list of all the Inno Setup [directory constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts).

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommend to write to **AppData** directory using InnoIDE. You better save user-specific data to a shared location first (**e.g. under {app}**) and have your application copy it from there on first startup.

more *https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036259/5929293*