# how do I set up my C# application to use program files for the app and app data for the DB?

Tags: c#, sqlite, inno-setup

I have a windows form application that I made for a local club.  I'm using inno setup to create the exe.
It defaulted the install location to program files where I learned that it makes the DB read only.  With some reading I found out that the best way to set up a program is to use program files for the app and app data for the DB.  How do I go about changing my program and my setup to use those different locations by default?

I have this in a utility class:

```
public static readonly string APP_FOLDER = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); 
public static readonly string DB_FILE_PATH = Path.Combine(APP_FOLDER, "train.sqlite3"); 
public static readonly string DB_BACKUP_FILE_PATH = Path.Combine(APP_FOLDER, "backup.sqlite3"); 
public static readonly string CONN_STR = string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", DB_FILE_PATH);
```

And this in DAOs:

```
using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(Utility.CONN_STR))
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the setup part your answer is here

[Write to AppData directory using InnoIDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151680/write-to-appdata-directory-using-innoide)

To read from the DB, well I can't give you an exact answer because I have no idea how you access the DB, but in .NET you access the appdata folder path with

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Hopefully from that you can set the path to your DB in your connection string.

I have this in a utility class

```
public static readonly string APP_FOLDER = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); 
public static readonly string DB_FILE_PATH = Path.Combine(APP_FOLDER, "train.sqlite3");
public static readonly string DB_BACKUP_FILE_PATH = Path.Combine(APP_FOLDER, "backup.sqlite3");
public static readonly string CONN_STR = string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", DB_FILE_PATH);
```

and this in DAOs

```
using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(Utility.CONN_STR)) { }
```

Comment: @Thranor Edit your question to add the information there. It's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: @Thranor just set APP_FOLDER to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`